Log-Based GDP Alert Policy Fails to Trigger Incidents and Send Emails
I'm following this tutorial.
Alert policy is created and I write a test log entry but no incident is created and no alert e-mail is sent.
My policy settings and status are bellow;
Configurations
Logs and Incidents
I checked this topic but no relevant solution was found.
What should be checked, and what needs to be fixed?
Additional information:
Notification Channels

This isn't a programming question and so is unsuited to Stack overflow. I am unable to repro your issue; the tutorial works for me. You show that logs are being matched but you didn't include the notification channels. Since you're not receiving the alert, I suspect that's the cause of your error.

Thank you for your advice. My screen shot doesn't contain Notification Channels but I already set an e-mail and the notificatio channel works for another alert policy. I tested the notification channel for the VM CPU usage tutorial.
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options?hl=en#test-channel

Okay, well that's a good proof point. So the alert exists, it's definitely catching logs,. You also know the notification channel works. I'm at a loss.
